# Indoor Atlas: Fatal Exception - IdaSensorReadingManager

Tags: android

I am using the [IndoorAtlas SDK](https://developer.indooratlas.com/dashboard) to draw a map and the current position.
I have successfully done this and run the application on my phone. But
when I run my application on a Tab (7 inch) I am getting the following error:

```
06-05 14:44:34.476: E/AndroidRuntime(6957): FATAL EXCEPTION: IdaSensorReadingManager
06-05 14:44:34.476: E/AndroidRuntime(6957): Process: com.kcompute.campuscompass, PID: 6957
06-05 14:44:34.476: E/AndroidRuntime(6957): java.lang.IllegalStateException: unable to continue, mandatory sensor missing, type: 2
06-05 14:44:34.476: E/AndroidRuntime(6957):     at com.indooratlas._internal.an.a(SourceFile:450)
06-05 14:44:34.476: E/AndroidRuntime(6957):     at com.indooratlas._internal.an.c(SourceFile:414)
06-05 14:44:34.476: E/AndroidRuntime(6957):     at com.indooratlas._internal.an.b(SourceFile:40)
06-05 14:44:34.476: E/AndroidRuntime(6957):     at com.indooratlas._internal.an$a.handleMessage(SourceFile:772)
06-05 14:44:34.476: E/AndroidRuntime(6957):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-05 14:44:34.476: E/AndroidRuntime(6957):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
06-05 14:44:34.476: E/AndroidRuntime(6957):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tablet does not have magnetic field sensor (compass): unable to continue, mandatory sensor missing, type: 2.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the IndoorAtlas SDK requires three sensors: magnetometer, accelerometer and gyroscope. This exception will be thrown if one of them is missing. In my case, it was the gyroscope that is missing from Moto X Style (or Pure Edition).

I'd recommend that you install an App like "Phone Tester" which display data from all sensors as inform which sensors your phone doesn't have.